# Where is "require" defined?

Tags: raku, rakudo, mop

I have been looking in [Rakudo source](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/) for the implementation of [`require`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/modules#index-entry-require), first out of curiosity and second because I wanted to know if it was returning something.

I looked up `sub require` and it returned [this hit](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/e9351cbaa961c4d1e4ef8b4cb52418d55766a8d6/src/core/operators.pm6#L606), which actually seems to be the source for require, but it's called `sub REQUIRE_IMPORT`. It returns `Nil` and is declared as such, which pretty much answers my original question. But now my question is: Where's the mapping from that sub to `require`? Is it really the implementation for that function? Are there some other functions that are declared that way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`require` is not a sub, but rather a statement control (so, in the same category of things like `use`, `if`, `for`, etc.) It is [parsed by the Perl 6 grammar](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/99d94db4dd187d09954f0bd2698c676e292bbbd3/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L1329) and there are a few different cases that are accepted. It is [compiled in the Perl 6 actions](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/99d94db4dd187d09954f0bd2698c676e292bbbd3/src/Perl6/Actions.nqp#L2112), which has quite a bit to handle.

Much of the work is delegated to the various `CompUnit` objects, which are also involved with `use`/`need`. It also has to take care of stubbing symbols that the `require` will bring in, since the set of symbols in a given lexical scope is fixed at compile time, and the `REQUIRE_IMPORT` utility sub is involved with the runtime symbol import too.

The answer to your question as to what it will evaluate to comes at the end of the method:

```
    $past.push($<module_name>
               ?? self.make_indirect_lookup($longname.components())
               !! $<file>.ast);
```

Which means:

- If it was a `require Some::Module` then evaluate to a lookup of `Some::Module`
- If it was a `require $file` style case, evaluate to the filename